# jQuery script returning empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, soundcloud

I'm trying to return the href link of a song that is tagged with 'Electronic' on SoundCloud.

What my script supposedly does, is that it searches the list items SoundCloud generates for it's songs on my stream, and if the song has an 'Electronic' tag, it then grabs the href link, linking to that particular song. It then iterates through the list items; generating an array of links for me.

I believe I have my code right, but using Chrome's Javascript console, I am being returned with an empty array.

Here's my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         jQuery for SoundCloud
// @namespace    jQueryForSoundCloud
// @description  This userscript returns the href link of all songs tagged 'Electronic'
// ==/UserScript==

// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://web.archive.org/web/20161221181738/http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
    var href = $('li.listItems .spanClass:contains(Electronic)').map(function() {
        return $(this).parent('a').attr('href')
    }).get();

    console.log(href)
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Using this code with JSFiddle, and generating a test HTML Document with the exact same layout, I am able to return an array; however, using the JS console with SoundCloud, I am being returned with '[]' and undefined.

What do you think I am doing wrong, and what can I do to fix this problem I am having?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My code only works in JSFiddle when I press CTRL+ENTER on the Javascript window JSFiddle offers; an array is returned with the values inside. If I press CTRL+ENTER in Chrome's JS console with my script loaded, an empty array is returned. What's up with that?

Comment: Why do you use web.archive.org to get a copy of jQuery? O.o

Comment: Is the Soundcloud page's content loaded dynamically? If so, your script may be running while the page's various Ajax calls are still running, and none of those elements exist yet.

Comment: @Andreas I don't really have any clue to be honest... That code snippet was 'borrowed' from another question so that I can inject my jQuery script into SoundCloud.

Comment: JQuery is defined - as you are not getting the `$ is not defined` error.. so im guessing your problem is in the selector.

Comment: @PaulRoub I load up soundcloud.com/stream and do not interact with the page at all after that. I inject my script as is; I wouldn't think anything would be running under the hood as I'm not interacting with the page?

Comment: @JFit This code snippet works on JSFiddle for some reason, with the exact same markup. I don't see any reason why it would be my selector?

Comment: Nothing to do with page interaction. I'm wondering if, as many sites do, Soundcloud loads a "skeleton" page with just the structure and scripts, then starts loading the songs / etc. If so, your script may run before all that is completed. In your JSFiddle, of course, all of the markup is already present and ready to go. Did you create the JSFiddle by viewing the Soundcloud page source, or by getting HTML from the dev tools / inspector? If it's the former, my guess doesn't apply. If the latter, try a `setTimeout()` around your `addJQuery` call to see if waiting a few seconds fixes things.

Comment: @PaulRoub Setting a timeout does not fix things; I am guessing what you say is true. You can refer to my edit at the end of the post if that helps. I guess I may have to look for another language that performs as I'd like it to. Thank you for your help.